# 5 min train to bus connection in Pflach, Austria, feasible?

Tags: short-connections, austria

I am looking to go from Garmisch-Partenkirchen, Germany to Füssen, Germany by public transport.

Both [bahn.de](https://bahn.de) and [öbb](https://fahrplan.oebb.at) show two *practical* connections for this journey

A direct bus and a train+bus combination

```
1h0min
Garmisch-Partenkirchen
RB 60 (5540) - S 7
-> Pfronten-Steinach
14:04
Pflach Pl. 1
14:09 - 21min
Pflach Kulturhaus, Österreich
Bus 100
-> Bahnhof, Füssen
14:30 Bahnhof, Füssen
```

Due to the timetable, the train+bus connection is more practical for me, but I would like not to commit to it seeing the minuscule connection time of 5 min (including an 80 m walk to the stop) and that the 100 bus only runs every two hours.

I would have liked to see historical timing, but since it is a regional train I couldn't find something akin to [ZugFinder](https://zugfinder.net) (not affiliated)

Is this is a feasible connection at all?

Comment: Google Maps suggest the same, along with a similar alternative via Reutte in Tirol (same train and bus, just a different place to switch from one to the other). The connection time is actually 5 minutes, not three, though that hardly makes a difference. I wonder if the bus waits for the train in case of delays?

Comment: The train and bus seem to run in parallell for some time. You can take the train up to Vils, and have more time to catch the bus.

Comment: For me, Deutsche Bahn suggests 
14:04 Garmisch-Partenkirchen RB 60 - 15:17 Vils Stadt // 15:29 Vils in Tirol Untertor Bus 100 - 15:50 Bahnhof Füssen (at least for today)

Comment: For Austria, I would recommend using BusBahnBim App

Comment: As a French reading this, I am amazed at how you people provide exact arrival times, to the minute, and make plans around that in a several minutes window.

Comment: @WoJ I am French as well... and tbf, this was scary seeing how delayed the whole German train system is as a whole

Comment: @NicolasFormichella - still it looks like they are better than our SNCF/RATP (https://www.lesechos.fr/industrie-services/tourisme-transport/ponctualite-des-trains-la-france-a-toujours-du-retard-1367996)

Comment: @Wol I have travelled **a lot** on a specific route (Paris-Rennes). On this route, delays are incredibly rare (like for maybe 30-40 trips in the last 5y in both direction, there was only one major (>15min)) delay... First ICE into Germany this week... 2h late. And that's the theme here, you need to plan a 2h buffer if you ever take an ICE/IC, look at ZugFinder above. Most ICE routes don't cross the 50% of punctuality

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When I look at the time table, it seems to me as if there is a planned transfer between the train and the bus in Reutte, the station before Pflach. I reckon that you have a better chance that the bus waits for the train (and vice versa) there, rather in Pflach.

In Reutte, there are the following arrivals and departures around 14:00:

- 13:58 the oncoming S7 arrives from Pfronten-Steinach
- 14:00 your train arrives
- 14:00 the 100 bus arrives (according to the VVT timetable)
- 14:01 the oncoming S7 departs for Garmisch-Partenkirchen
- 14:02 your train departs
- 14:05 the 100 bus departs

The two trains are passing eachother in Reutte (it's a single track line), but with the bus having a 5 minute planned stop overlapping with both trains, it looks very much to me as if this is a planned transfer.

Comment: Definitely this. And in Reutte the bus driver has a chance to see if the train arrived and if there are people coming.

Answer (score 8):

That should be fine. I have no direct experience with this exact station, but do have a fair bit of experience with other tiny train stations in Germany. It's not uncommon to have a short walk from the train tracks to the next intersection and the schedules are typically designed to accommodate this. Google maps says it's a one minute walk and if everything is reasonably on time and there are no issues with luggage or mobility that should be doable. Some of the smaller/local buses will indeed wait if the train is delayed but it's not guaranteed.

One caveat: if you get out on the "wrong" side of the train you may have to wait until the train has left before you can cross the tracks.

It's probably a good idea to familiarize yourself with the area so that you know where to go and don't need to look around, orient yourself and/or take a wrong turn. There is probably no signage.

[image: Google Maps satellite view of walking path from train station to bus stop]

Answer (score 5):

After listening to the advice of Tor-Einar Jarnbjo, I decided to abandon the idea of doing it in Pflach but instead in *Reutte in Tyrol*

It was a smooth delay-free connection, with 3 min left before depature of the 100 bus

The bus station in Reutte is located at the rear of the train and the bus departs from Stop C

After looking again at the Google Maps, a connection in Pflach looks a lot more riskier, as compared to doing in Reutte where you cross the tracks on the rear of the train, since you have to cross in front of the train to turn left.

Comment: I must admit that I am not at all very familiar with the railway station in Reutte, but going from the train platform to the bus stop, don't you have to cross in front of the S7 train going to Garmisch-Partenkirchen?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Not that I can remember, I *landed* on the left platform and the Garmish train was on the right platform opposite to the station

Answer (score 0):

This is something I would never do.
It is very common that Deutsche Bahn trains are late. It might be only 2-3 minutes, but that's already enough to miss the bus. And for a bus that comes only every two hours, the risk is too high.
If I were you, I would take the direct connection.

Comment: I have experienced delays indeed, but he direct bus is out of the question due to its timing. This t+b is the only viable connextion for me

Comment: Is this actually a DB or ÖBB train?

Comment: @jcaron DB train